# Jonckheere-Terpstra Trend Test Use and Effect Size

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, trend

I would like to find out if there is a statistically significant increase among four groups. I have 4 ordinal groups (ex group 1 is count 1-20, group 2 is count 21-30 etc) and I have data for each of these groups where each group's sample size is not equal. The data within each group has a range, all start with 0 but some go higher than others. I want to see if there is an overall increase across the groups. I have applied the JT test, and obtain these results: z = 5.49, r = 0.21. This tells me that the test was significant, but that the effect size is negligible.

1) Was that the correct usage of this test? 
2) Is my interpretation of the test correct? 
3) Is there a more appropriate test I could implement?

The equation to calculate r is  Z/sq rt(N) where z is the z-score of the test and n is the sample size.

Comment: What is the "data within each group"? Is it ordinal or interval or what? JT is usually used on crosstabulated data where there is an order in one or both dimensions

Comment: More information about your situation would help; from what I can see so far I probably wouldn't have done J-T on this (though I do think it's used a lot less often than it could be) -- but it's hard to understand what's going on (you have counts?) so I am not sure. What makes you say the effect size is negligible/what's "r"? (I can imagine computing Kendall's tau in a situation where you'd use J-T, but I don't know that I'd use it as a measure of effect size, and if that's what you're doing, I probably wouldn't have called 0.21 negligible. I presume you did something else there.)

Comment: Thank you both. To clarify, the groups represent a range of positive integers between 1-81 and are sorted into 4 groups. In each group, I have data, ( all data is continuous ranging from 0-99885456, but the 4 groups each have a different maximum value). I have the medians and means for each group (ex medians 1-729,2-2796,3-6418 and 4-4411). There is a slight increasing trend, and I am looking for a way to test it. If I plot the medians and correlate (line of best fit) them the R2 is 0.615. Is there a better way to check for this increasing trend?

Comment: @Glen_b, I have added the equation I used for r in the original question.